# Qual a diferença entre "dependencies" e "devDependencies"?

Tags: node.js, composer, npm, bower

Qual a diferença entre salvar um componente como **"dependencies"** ou **"devDependencies"** no **bower**, **npm**, **composer** entre outros que utilizam dessa estrutura ?

Comment: A melhor resposta já dada para essa questão. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies (Em Inglês)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR:

- `dependencies`: programas necessários para produção
- `devDependencies`: programas usados para desenvolvimento

Quando corremos `npm install` numa diretoria onde há um repositório e um `package.json`ambas as `dependencies` e `devDependencies` são instaladas.
Quando corremos o install com um pacote específico: `npm instal <pacote>` somente as `dependencias` (de produção) são instaladas, para instalar ambas usa-e a flag `--save-dev`: `npm instal <pacote> --save-dev`

---

### `dependencies`

`dependencies` são todos os programas necessários para a aplicação funcionar. A aplicação depende deles e têm de estar instalados senão a aplicação não corre. Caso se queira instalar somente as dependências de produção pode usar-se `npm install --production`.

Anteriormente para gravar uma dependência como essencial usávamos o comando:

```bash
npm install <pacote> --save
```

Mas desde o *npm v5* o `--save` não é mais necessário, pois o comportamento ocorre por padrão, mas se desejar impedir gravar você deve usar o parâmetro `--no-save`.

### `devDependencies`

`devDependencies` são todos os programas necessários para ambiente de desenvolvimento da aplicação. Pode ser tudo desde compressores de código, transpiladores, testes unitários, ferramentas de debug, etc. Estes não são necessários para a aplicação funcionar, mas sim para desenvolver ou testar.

Para gravar uma dependência como "dev":

```bash
npm install <pacote> --save-dev
```