# Babel pra quem nunca usou NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, babel

Talvez porque eu tenha uma experiência bem maior com PHP eu nunca fui muito fã de JavaScript.

Sempre achei a sintaxe da linguagem confusa e complicada e muitas vezes recorri a jQuery pra fazer coisas simples que muitos fariam com os pés nas costas.

Porém, nos últimos dias eu estava buscando um meio simples e elegante de pelo menos simular o básico de OOP que se tem com PHP no JavaScript, principal, mas não exclusivamente, herança.

Foi quando sem querer eu tropecei no ES2015 e a sintaxe por ele proposta me agradou bastante porque era bem o que eu queria, algo simples e direto e com um maior poder de Orientação a Objetos.

Mas, como sempre com relação às minhas aventuras com JavaScript, havia um porém: A ES2015 não é bem suportada pelos navegadores. Até mesmo o Chrome parece precisar que uma certa uma opção experimental esteja ativada pra que esses recursos funcionem.

Então, de novo, eu tropecei em algo chamado [Babel](http://babeljs.io/), que inclusive tem um editor online bacana que transcompila automaticamente.

O problema é que eu não tenho a menor idéia de sequer como começar a usar ele porque eu nunca usei o tal do NodeJS, que eu ouvia falar mas nunca dei importância por não gostar de JavaScript, e que, pelo visto, é um dos requerimentos.

Juro que tentei pesquisar algo mais palpável pra quem é completamente alienado à linguagem, mas cada artigo que eu lia era mais técnico que o outro, mencionando ainda mais coisas que eu nunca usei como um tal de Grunt, Gulp, Karma ou pior, sempre focado em ambiente Linux o que é e sempre foi bem dificil pra mim e, no final, nenhum artigo soube deixar claro o quê exatamente fazer.

Eu sei que isso foge bastante dos padrões da comunidade, mas eu resolvi arriscar porque lá atrás, quando o SOPT começou, era bastante comum dúvidas tontas como essa receberem respostas completas e bem redigidas (muitas vezes respondidas pelos próprios autores a fim de alavancar pontuação - o que eu acho errado) a título de agregação de conteúdo.

Eu meio que prevejo uma chuva de votos negativos, principalmente por pessoas que não gostam de ler e até mesmo o encerramento da questão como sendo muito ampla (apesar de não ser), mas se for possível um direcionamento seria extremamente útil pra mim e talvez para outros que ficam receosos em dar esse primeiro passo publicamente.

Comment: Legal! Mas qual é exatamente sua dúvida? Quanto ao uso do Babel? Por onde começar? Vantagens? Desvantagens? Uso do Node.js?

Comment: Principalmente por onde começar, desde a instalação do produto e aquilo que ele precisar. Caso se faça jus um adendo sobre vantagens e desvantagens, ótimo, seria bem vindo. Se for necessário aprender alguma coisa sobre o nodeJS pra poder usar o Babel, também seria interessante ter como informação.

Comment: Dúvida interessante, também gostaria de saber mais

Comment: Só uma coisa: a sintaxe de classes do ES2015 não te dá mais "poder de OO". Ela é basicamente açúcar sintático. Não é um bom caminho tentar replicar em JS o que você faz no PHP. Cada linguagem tem o seu estilo.

Comment: Quando eu disse mais poder de OO foi mais no sentido de aproximar àquilo que eu tenho com PHP, já que a sintaxe e algumas funcionalidades são bem parecidas.

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar dar apontadores. Coisas a ler e conceitos gerais.

Para testar JavaScript do futuro podes usar o jsFiddle com a linguagem "babel" ([exemplo aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/dwahlin/o93Lm0rc/)) ou codepen ([exemplo aqui](https://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/rjNEvV)), e há outros como o editor que referiste diretamente no Babel.

Para criar um projeto precisas de tomar algumas decisões em relação a tecnologias. O JavaScript desenvolve-se muito rápido agora, tecnologias relativamente recentes como o Gulp e o Grunt são noticias de ontem e menos usadas hoje.

Hoje em dia fala-se em fadiga de desenvolvimento, e refere-se exatamente ao teu problema. Para fazer um "hello world" é preciso instalar muita coisa que nunca se ouviu falar...

Sugestão de passos para criares um projeto a funcionar:

- instala o Node.js ([download aqui](https://nodejs.org/en/download/))

O Node.js é JavaScript no servidor. Podes [ler mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157034/o-que-%C3%A9-o-npm-e-o-node). Com ele vem o `NPM` que é um repositório de pacotes/plugins/programas. O Babel têm vários plugins, irás precisar de alguns.

As ultimas versões do Node já correm ES6, por isso podes escrever e testar código ES6 com ele.

O `package.json` é o ficheiro de configuração da aplicação onde guardas informações de dependências, para que tudo possa ser re-instalado noutra máquina com um simples `npm install`.

Para instalar plugins usa `npm install nomeDoPlugin` se juntares `-s` ele é gravado no `package.json`. Podes [ler mais sobre isso aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/163816/129)

Para exportar módulos e assim teres o código separado em ficheiros diferentes [podes ler aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55084/quando-usar-module-exports-ou-exports-no-node-js).

Para ler sobre versionamento no `package.json` [podes ler aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85531/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-sufixos-de-vers%C3%B5es-npm-e-o-que-fazem).

- instala o Github

Isto não é essencial, mas ajuda muito pois podes instalar projetos de exemplo com facilidade. Se não quiseres instalar podes sempre ir à página de um projeto e fazer download do `.zip`.

- Lê sobre transpiladores: babel, webpack, browserify, entre outros

O webpack e browserify convertem e copiam código para ser consumido. Durante o processo podem correr o babel internamente, mas também podes ter o babel a correr sozinho.  Dei um exemplo numa [outra resposta sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146397/129).

- Lê sobre como importar plugins para dentro do código.

Respondi [sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127445/129), mas basicamente nos ficheiros que vão ser transpilados para ES5 (para serem usados no browser) podes fazer:

```
var plugin = require('plugin'); // neste caso é uma bliblioteca que tens instalada
var plugin = require('./plugin'); // neste caso é um ficheiro de nome `plugin.js` na mesma diretoria que será importado
```

- testar uma aplicação

Sugiro instalares um "boilerplate" que é um projeto "chave na mão". Há muitos no Github, encontrei este que parece útil: https://github.com/developit/express-es6-rest-api

Esse projeto usa ES6, Express (que é uma biblioteca para fincionalidade de "servidor").

#### E depois?

Lê as sugestões / links que sugeri. Depois disso, quando surgirem dúvidas coloca aqui no site, isoladas, uma a uma em cada pergunta e vamos ajudar a resolver.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Então se eu instalar o NodeJS "apenas" pra rodar o Babel não tem problema, certo? Não vou precisar de um servidor que tenha suporte ao NodeJS pra rodar a aplicação depois de pronta

Comment: @user5613506 exato, podes usar o Node só como compilador de ficheiros `.js` que depois copias para o teu projeto. Tambem podes ter uma página HTML estática para os testar dentro do projeto Node sem precisares de ter um servidor a correr.